# Why do I need to install every Django dependency after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, python, django

I upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr) to 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), and I installed Python 3.4 and Django 1.9.2.

Now when I run a Django Project with:

```
python3.4 manage.py runserver
```

I get import errors for SciPy, xslt, NumPy, pylab and what not.

I'm installing the dependency one by one from last 30-40 minutes, but a new import error raises every time.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has Python 3.5 on default

Comment: yeah..I know that but my project uses 3.4 so I installed 3.4 too

Comment: Check here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-s-new-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I think you should use a virtualenv to work that project

Comment: http://devmartin.com/blog/2016/04/creating-a-virtual-environment-with-python3.4-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial-xerus/

Answer (score 1):

Python packages are specific to a Python version.
Each Python version has its own library of packages,
isolated from the libraries of other versions at the filesystem level.
Packages installed for one library will not be available for another.

So when you install a new version of Python,
you will have to install in its library any packages that you need,
even if you installed them with the previous version.
This also means that the previously installed packages remain available with the previous version of Python.

Lastly,
it's recommended to install Django and its dependencies in a `virtualenv`.
That will not save you from the "pain" of reinstalling the dependencies when you change the version,
this is just a good measure to avoid polluting your system with packages that are only needed by Django, and it also allows having multiple versions of Django and its dependencies independently.
And when I say "pain" of reinstalling dependencies,
when following good practices it's not supposed to be a pain at all.
The dependencies should be declared in a `requirements.txt` file at the project's root, and reinstalling everything should be a matter of `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: but I see the same error when i run with Python 3.5